# Why SQL binary convert function results a non-0101... value?

Tags: sql-server, binary, varbinary

Why when I use the command in SQL Server 2005

```
select convert(varbinary(16),N'123')
```

results `0x310032003300` and not `1111011`?

Comment: Because it is a hexadecimal representation of the binary data.

Also you are converting a unicode string not an integer. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You're converting a Unicode string to binary, not a number. SQL Server also gives you the answer in base 16 (hexadecimal)

Comment: The simple answer is that it's binary data. but it's not useful/convenient to display it in binary form with ones and zeroes. You're probably just misunderstanding the term a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Basically each letter of '123' gets converted to it's UCS-2(basically the ASCII value padded to make it a double byte) value in the three double bytes of 0x3100, 0x3200, 0x3300, and concatenated together in a varbinar.

Hopefully that answers **why** you see this behavior.  **If you convert to an int first you may see what you were *perhaps* hoping for instead:**

```
select convert(varbinary(16),cast(N'123' as int))
```

produces hex value `0x0000007B` which in binary is `1111011`

See http://www.asciitable.com/ the entry for numeric 3, the hex representation is 0x33 which corresponds to the same entry in unicode: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html (this pattern does not necessarily hold true for all ASCII/unicode characters, but does for the 10 integers).